# Xamarin Studio 2 - latest stable update - Error executing task Aapt: The source sequence is empty

Tags: android, xamarin, aapt

I am using the trial version of Xamarin Studio for my final year project consisting an android application. Everything went smooth initially. But today right after updating to the latest stable version, i encountered an error (as stated on the title of this post).

The build log is as follows:

> Building Solution: MyActivity.Mobile (Debug)
>
> Building: MCAAndroid (Debug)
>
> Build started 05/18/2013 17:04:44.
>
> Project
>   "/Users/hazimanabhmy/Projects/MyActivity.Mobile/MCAAndroid/MCAAndroid.csproj"
>   (Build target(s)):
>
> Target _CheckProjectItems:
>       CheckProjectItems Task
>         NativeLibraries:
>         JavaLibraries:
>         JavaSourceFiles:
>
> Target _ComputeAndroidAssetsPaths:
>         ResourceFiles:
>           Assets/WebUI/newsfeed.html
>           Assets/WebUI/images/bg_content.png
>           Assets/WebUI/css/style.css
>           Assets/WebUI/images/flag.png
>         IntermediateFiles:
>
> Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir: Skipping target
>   "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because its outputs are up-to-date.
>
> Target _ComputeAndroidResourcePaths:
>         ResourceFiles:
>           Resources/values/Strings.xml
>           Resources/drawable/Icon.png
>           Resources/layout/Login.axml
>           Resources/drawable/le_cool_logo.png
>           Resources/drawable/bg.jpg
>           Resources/drawable/icon_password.png
>           Resources/drawable/Icon_user.png
>           Resources/layout/Home.axml
>           Resources/drawable/info.png
>           Resources/drawable/settings.png
>           Resources/drawable/help.png
>           Resources/drawable/bg_content.png
>           Resources/drawable/shadow_black.9.png
>           Resources/drawable/cog.png
>           Resources/drawable/tools.png
>           Resources/layout/ReadMatric.axml
>           Resources/drawable/matric.jpg
>           Resources/drawable/mcalogo.png
>         IntermediateFiles:
>
> Target _GenerateAndroidResourceDir: Skipping target
>   "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because its outputs are up-to-date.
>
> Target _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
>       MonoAndroid Tools: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/
>       MonoAndroid Framework: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-10;/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/2.1
>       MonoAndroid Binaries: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/bin/
>       Android NDK: 
>       Android SDK: /Users/hazimanabhmy/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86/
>       Java SDK: /usr/
>
> Target _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
>       GetAndroidPackageName Task
>         ManifestFile: /Users/hazimanabhmy/Projects/MyActivity.Mobile/MCAAndroid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml
>         AssemblyName: MCAAndroid
>         PackageName: MCAAndroid.MCAAndroid
>
> Target _BuildDependencies:
>       Resolved library outputs:
>
> Target _ExtractLibraryProjectImports:
>         Assemblies: 
>           /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll
>           /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll
>           /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-10/Mono.Android.dll
>           /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll
>         Jars: 
>         ResolvedResourceDirectories:
>
> Target _GetLibraryImports:
>         NativeLibraries: 
>         Jars:
>
> Target _CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries:
>         JavaSourceFiles:
>         JavaLibraries:
>
> Target _UpdateAndroidResgen:
>         AdditionalResourceDirectories:  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
>   error : Error executing task Aapt: The source sequence is empty Task
>   "Aapt" execution -- FAILED Done building target "_UpdateAndroidResgen"
>   in project
>   "/Users/hazimanabhmy/Projects/MyActivity.Mobile/MCAAndroid/MCAAndroid.csproj".--
>   FAILED
>
> Done building project
>   "/Users/hazimanabhmy/Projects/MyActivity.Mobile/MCAAndroid/MCAAndroid.csproj".--
>   FAILED
>
> Build FAILED. Errors:
>
> /Users/hazimanabhmy/Projects/MyActivity.Mobile/MCAAndroid/MCAAndroid.csproj
>   (Build) ->
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets
>   (_UpdateAndroidResgen target) ->
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
>   error : Error executing task Aapt: The source sequence is empty
>
> 0 Warning(s)  1 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1048310
>
> ---------------------- Done ----------------------
>
> Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

I couldn't find the cause. Would someone help me?

I have asked this same question on Xamarin.Android's forum, and still waiting for their answer. But i think i could gather more resources and insights from experts here.

Comment: I've received an answer from Xamarin forum. It appears that the solution is similar to what suggested in 

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/13817/

Also, an instruction was actually placed in the readme inside private Android SDK folder.

Comment: +1 this helped me out today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a recent change/bug in Xamarin.Android that expects to be used with Android tools rev. 22 or later where appt has been moved around in the sdk directory (from tools to build-tools). You need to go into the android sdk manager and update the SDK tools to revision 22 (or better) and also install the new build-tools package. [image]