# How to Get GPS base on Wifi using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

This code base on the link below: 
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/part_3_-_location_services

I could not get any Lat/Lon ( Gps/Wifi)

The code is below :

I have added:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
&lt:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Android.Locations

```
using System;

using Android.App;

using Android.Content;

using Android.Runtime;

using Android.Views;

using Android.Widget;

using Android.OS;


//-- add these


using Android.Locations;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Threading;

using System.Text;

using System.Linq;

using System.Xml;



namespace GPSWifi

{

    [Activity (Label = "GPSWifi", MainLauncher = true)]

    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
                    int count = 1;

        private LocationManager _locMgr;



    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


              InitializeLocationManager();      

    }



    private void InitializeLocationManager()
    {

        _locMgr = (LocationManager) GetSystemService(LocationService);

        var locationCriteria = new Criteria();

        locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement;

        locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.NoRequirement;

        string locationProvider = _locMgr.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);

        _locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (locationProvider, 2000, 1, this);       

        }



    protected override void OnResume ()
    {

        base.OnResume ();

    _locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GpsProvider, 2000, 1, this);


               }



    protected override void OnPause ()
    {

        base.OnPause ();
        _locMgr.RemoveUpdates (this);

    }



    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) {}


    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) {}




    public void OnLocationChanged (Location location)
    {

    var locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.locationTextView);

    locationText.Text = String.Format ("Latitude = {0}, Longitude = {1}",

                                               location.Latitude, location.Longitude);



       }

   }

}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

-- Error Message :

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): 
>   Error MSB4018: The "Aapt" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildToolsUtils.GetBuildToolsPath(String
>   androidSdkDirectory)
>
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.GenerateFullPathToTool()
>
> at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ComputePathToTool()
>
> at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
>
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.Execute()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()
>   (MSB4018) (GPSWifi)

Answer (score 0):

This error: `The "Aapt" task failed unexpectedly.` has just started occurring recently - I think it's to do with the very latest sdk's from Android/Google - I think they've moved a file location.

Check other questions like [Xamarin Studio 2 - latest stable update - Error executing task Aapt: The source sequence is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623222/xamarin-studio-2-latest-stable-update-error-executing-task-aapt-the-source)

Then check with Xamarin support - they'll issue an update to fix this.

Comment: Thank. This issue is solved. Base on the sample code, it is possible to get Gps Lat/Lon by running it in emulator? There is nothing show up when I run this sample code.